# Connecting Apple ID to multiple iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm not sure if this question already exists, since I'm not exactly sure what to search for.

So here's the deal:

1. I have an Apple Dev account linked to the email ash@ashmenon.com. I've worked on an app in the member center, and I've also got an iTunes Connect account connected to this same Apple ID.
2. Right now I'm working on an app (Super Marvel App) as part of a team (let's call it Team Marvel) My Apple ID has been added to that team, as an 'Admin'. So when I go into the member center, the MC asks me which organisation I want to choose (my own, or Team Marvel).
3. However, the agent for this team was unable to add my Apple ID in iTunes Connect, as it belongs to an existing dev account. So what we did was to add a plus-suffixed version of my email, in this case 'ash+marvel@ashmenon.com'.
4. Problem is, I'm the developer for the team, not the agent (he's non-tech), so any archiving, submission, validation, and exporting comes from my XCode. But when I try and submit/validate my archived app, it tells me that my organization does not have permission to submit this application. (not sure if this is important, but the name of the organisation it displays during this error is not the same as the name of the development team that I selected earlier in the submission process.
5. I tried adding the ash+marvel@ashmenon.com address as one of the Apple ID accounts in XCode, but it tells me 'Error Fetching Developer Info'. I presume this is because the account in question is not an actual Apple Dev account.

For now I've worked around the process by submitting via Application Loader, but it feels like I'm hacking the system somewhat.

QUESTION 1: 
Is there a proper way of doing this that I'm missing out? Gut instinct tells me that this hack-esque workaround is going to bite me in the backend later on.

QUESTION 2: 
Is the Team Marvel agent required to do all iTunes Connect submissions himself? This seems like a very counter-intuitive approach considering this is Apple we're talking about.

Any assistance is much appreciated. Stay awesome, you guys.

NOTE:
Names of applications and teams have been changed for privacy reasons, and because Marvel is infinitely cooler than anything else.

Comment: How did he add you to his team in iTunes connect ? The issue is in that part. Usually when I hire a new person to my team, I invite them using the mail id (Already registered in member center), I didn't get any issues till now.

Comment: @MidhunMP I'm not sure exactly how, but I assume that he added me via my email. He initially tried using my usual email 'ash@ashmenon.com', but that was denied, saying "the email address you entered already belongs to an iTunes Connect account. To continue, enter a different email address".

Comment: That sounds like ash@ashmenon.com is your AppleId, and he tried to create another AppleId with the same email address. And that's obviously not possible.

Comment: this is such a pain point. supposedly there are upcoming changes that might help in this area. see https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=302

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Do not use this approach any more. Apple has *finally* fixed iTunes Connect, Developer Center and Xcode to properly handle one Apple ID for multiple organizations. Add the same Apple ID to as many organizations in both systems as you need.

---

I believe there is finally a way to make this work while preserving your sanity in Xcode 6.3.2.

The main trick is to make sure that your iTunes Connect account and Member Center account Apple id's are the same for any particular organization. It looks like Xcode assumes that and tries to use the Member Center Apple ID to access iTunes Connect.

So, as mentioned in the question, make sure and use a "+folder" style of email address to avoid creating and managing a whole bunch of real email accounts. But here's the crucial part - add that "+folder" style account to Member Center (i.e. invite the "+folder" account) for that organization and remove your plain Apple ID if you were using it there.

I.e. *don't use Member Center's ability to associate multiple organizations with one account*. That will just confuse Xcode if you also need to access multiple iTunes Connect accounts. Use one "+folder" account for each organization you are working with and add that Apple ID to both iTunes Connect and Member Center.

Comment: Can you use a simple Apple ID associated to the alias, or do you have to configure it as a developer account? Don't think you can be a Team Admin (hence dealing with distribution provisioning) without having a developer license associated to the Apple ID.

Comment: I would try using both – i.e. use the simple apple ID to do Team Admin stuff and add the alias to build and sign in Xcode.

Comment: Not sure I understand the complete configuration you suggest. My current setup:

- since there's no alternative (even if WWDC 2015 Session 302 states otherwise), I am using an alias Apple ID to be a Technical member of the client's team in iTunes Connect;
- I am using my official (regular) Apple ID as an Admin in Member Center for the client's team. I use that account for certificates and provisioning profiles.

Comment: I also tried adding the iTC "alias" Apple ID in the account list in Xcode, but no luck. You suggest not to use the regular Apple ID in Member Center, but the iTC alias as well. What about the dev license? Is it possible to manage certificates and provisioning with a free account, as a member of a team? I tried this (adding the alias as an Admin in MC, and creating a Dev Certificate) but Xcode can't download certificates and profiles, for the alias account, marked as "Free" (not Admin as it should be). The submit fails because Xcode can't find a valid iTC account (even if it's there).

Comment: The basic goal is to make sure you build and sign code with the exact same email address being used in both iTC and Member Center. Using +aliases is the easiest way to make that happen. How this works may have changed since "Free" accounts showed up. When adding someone to a team, I didn't think it mattered what plan that particular person had signed up for - it only mattered what the admin of the team had signed up for. It's possible team members need to have paid developer accounts for this to work.

Comment: Or, make sure that you are inviting a new Apple ID that is not in the developer program yet (a new +alias) and make sure *not* to sign it up into the Free program. That's just some educated guesses as to what is going on.

Comment: Turns out I was using a wrong iTunes Connect alias when adding it to Xcode, because I did a lot of tests and ended up mixing some credentials. I managed to make everything work simply using my official account in every Member Center Team (for my various clients), multiple +aliases for each iTunes Connect Team and adding every account (the official one and the +aliases) in Xcode. I can submit apps without any issues. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that's the way it is. iTunes Connect is not linked to Member center, and unlike Member center, it cannot handle multiple accounts per email. I'm on the same boat as you. Always need to save an IPA file and submit from Application Loader. Wish we could select the proper iTunes Connect account

Comment: Note that now (at least with Xcode 7 GM?) you can't event export for distribution on the App Store from the Organizer in this case as well. You have to have a separate Apple ID specific for the team associated with the app you're uploading in your Xcode account list for this to work when it didn't used to be the case.

Comment: In my Xcode 7 GM the Export > Save for iOS App Store Deployment still works as usual

Comment: @AriBraginsky Same issue here, can't export IPAs and getting the same "No accounts with iTunes Connect access" error message. Adding the Apple ID (alias) I use to be added in the relevant team has no effects.